# How to show already selected data as selected/checked using 'ss-multiselect-dropdown' in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am using 'ss-multiselect-dropdown' for multi-select dropdown.
I have selected few options from dropdown and saved the data.
When I will update data next time, that time already selected data should be displayed as selected/checked.
For single select it works with two way data binding '[(ngModel)] ', however it does not work with multi selected values.
How to show/set already selected data as selected/checked using 'ss-multiselect-dropdown'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please show some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

For this you could use an Array:

```
selecOptions = [];
```

HTML side:

```
                    <ss-multiselect-dropdown
                            [options]="finalServices"
                            [texts]="myTexts"
                            [settings]="mySettings"
                            [(ngModel)]="selecOptions"
                            (ngModelChange)="onChangeService($event)"
                            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                    </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Remember the selection in this is based on the `id` present in the object array of `finalServices`.

Comment: I was not using ngModel variable as an array (yash_DedSec has pointed exactly the same). Declared an array and added already selected values in that, and it worked. Thank you Amit Chigadani and Yash.

Answer (score 2):

Created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgbhtNs3RdRcgZs2SDHm) to play with multi-select.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IMultiSelectSettings, IMultiSelectTexts } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown';
import { MultiselectDropdownModule} from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
  `,
})
export class App {
  optionsModel: number[] = [ 2, 3];

// Settings configuration
mySettings: IMultiSelectSettings = {
    enableSearch: true,
    checkedStyle: 'fontawesome',
    buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default btn-block',
    dynamicTitleMaxItems: 3,
    displayAllSelectedText: true
};

// Text configuration
myTexts: IMultiSelectTexts = {
    checkAll: 'Select all',
    uncheckAll: 'Unselect all',
    checked: 'item selected',
    checkedPlural: 'items selected',
    searchPlaceholder: 'Find',
    searchEmptyResult: 'Nothing found...',
    searchNoRenderText: 'Type in search box to see results...',
    defaultTitle: 'Select',
    allSelected: 'All selected',
};

// Options
myOptions: IMultiSelectOption[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Volvo'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Honda'},
    { id: 3, name: 'BMW'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Audi'},
];

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,MultiselectDropdownModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more details refer [here](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect#customize).